# Importing HoloEverywhere into Eclipse: Error: No resource found that matches the given name

Tags: android, eclipse, android-holo-everywhere

I cannot get [HoloEverywhere](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere) to work in Eclipse. Eclipse shows 606 errors in `themes-core.xml` and `themes.xml`, all saying

```
error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'activatedBackgroundIndicator'
```

(Or another attributes).

As an example, right at the beginning of [themes-core.xml](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere/blob/master/library/res/values/themes-core.xml), the line that contains the above mentioned error is:

```
<item name="activatedBackgroundIndicator">@drawable/activated_background_holo</item>
```

I have imported HoloEverywhere to Eclipse using EGit.
I have also added ActionBarSherlock to my workspace and linked it to HoloEverywhere correctly (All classes from ActionBarSherlock are resolved correctly in the project).

I searched SO for a solution, but unfortunately could not find one.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found out what was causing the problem:

Android library projects have to be added via the Android tab in the Project settings, not via the Java Build path.
So, for adding the ActionbarSherlock dependency you have to open the settings of the HoloEverywhere project, choose the "Android" tab, click add and choose the ActionBarSherlock project.

I hope this helps future readers.

Comment: Hey man can you be a little more specific on this issue? What project settings? There's only project properties. I added the the actionbarsherlock library to HoloEverywhere, but still I'm getting the errors in themes-core.xml. Any thing else you had to change. Let me know, thanks!

Comment: Yes, it's in the project properties. How did you add the actionbarsherlock library? Did you use the "Android" tab from the left? It seems you cannot link Android projects through the Java Build Path tab, which I had used before. Linking abs via the Android tab did the trick for me.